# Crash from call registerAsSystemApp iOS 11.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9.3-beta

I have CustomClass: UIApplication

in main.m

`retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([CustomClass class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`

When I launch in iOS 11.2.2 It's Ok. If I launch in iOS 11.3 beta application crashed with reason:

`+[CustomClass registerAsSystemApp]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1b4ff8648`

```
    Call stack: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001836bc250 <redacted> + 252
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001828845ec objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001836c9488 <redacted> + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001836c1a74 <redacted> + 1380
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001835a7b0c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    5   UIKit                               0x000000018dbcb744 <redacted> + 852
    6   UIKit                               0x000000018d9cc1e8 UIApplicationMain + 184
    7   company.product                   0x0000000100ceb264 main + 176
    8   libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000183021fc0 <redacted> + 4
)   libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception
```

I can't understand why?

**UPD**
in Simulator iOS 11.3 work great...but from device I get crash

**UPD2** CustomClass

**.h**

```
@interface CustomClass : UIApplication {
    TCBIdleService *_idleService;
    LocationManager *_locationManager;
    TCBUserSession *_userSession;
}

+ (CustomClass *)sharedApp;
+ (NSString *)pushNotificationTokenKey;

- (void)loginWithUserInfo:(UserInfoMto *)userInfo;
- (void)logout;
- (void)registerPushNotifications;
```

**.m**

```
@interface CustomClass ()<TCBIdleServiceObserving, UIAlertViewDelegate, QCSSendListener>
```

[image: SIGABRT]

Comment: Can you show your `CustomClass`?

Comment: @lee This class has 325 rows. What specifically need to show? The only thing that has time to call from Custom Class it:
```+ (void)load {
// Installing handler in app's delegate do not allow to intercept uncaught exceptions thrown by init method.
    InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler();
}```

Comment: Assuming you're the one calling `registerAsSystemApp`, check first to see whether the class responds to that selector.

Comment: @PhillipMills, like this? breakpoint in body ```- (void) load```
```(lldb) po [CustomClass registerAsSystemApp]
false```

Comment: I was thinking of a runtime check like: `if ([[CustomClass class] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerAsSystemApp)]) {}`.

Comment: @PhillipMills, this return true

Comment: So, you're saying that `if ([[CustomClass class] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerAsSystemApp)]) { [CustomClass registerAsSystemApp]; }` crashes in the same way?  That sounds like a bug even for a private API.

Comment: Show your `registerAsSystemApp` body method. If every thing just work as @PhillipMills mentioned above, so I think you need to report bug to Apple.

Comment: @PhillipMills Stop, If ```[CustomClass registerAsSystemApp];``` is called in the body of the loop, then the application will not even be compiled. ```No known class method for selector 'registerAsSystemApp'```

Comment: @lee The ```CustomClass``` does't implement the method ```registerAsSystemApp```.

Comment: I thought that the method should be called from the parent class. I do not understand why this method is generally called, it is also private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my class in the project was named `MBApp`(this is CustomClass), it turns out that this name intersects with a class from a `MobileBackup.framework` that already has this class. Therefore, the method `registerAsSystemApp` was called from the `MobileBackup.framework` and naturally did not find it there. That is, the solution for me was to change the name of my `MBApp` class. The only puzzle is why it did not happen before, since the library with the class exists with iOS 5. Thanks for all the help and sorry that I did not write the original class name, because this is confendential information.